# Are visibility declations necessary when using a shared library on Unix-like systems?

Tags: c, linux, macos, cmake, visibility

When using CMake's [GenerateExportHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) on Linux/macOS, it generates something like this by default for shared libraries:

```c
#  ifndef SOMELIB_EXPORT
#    ifdef somelib_EXPORTS
        /* We are building this library */
#      define SOMELIB_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#    else
        /* We are using this library */
#      define SOMELIB_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#    endif
#  endif
```

Using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` in the *"We are building this library"* section is important. It ensures that public symbols will be visible in the library.

But does `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` do anything at all in the *"We are using this library"* section? My understanding is that the visibility of symbols is already set when building the library, and cannot be changed when using it. Thus, the visibility declaration is completely unnecessary when *using* the library. Is this correct?

(Note: I understand that on Windows `SOMELIB_EXPORT` would be defined as `__declspec(dllimport)`, which is in fact necessary when using the library. However, this question concerns solely Linux and macOS, not Windows.)

Comment: Just pointing out that using  `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` is necessary only when compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden`, but you should always build libraries in that way.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the library you don't need to define the attribute, as the symbols are loaded by the OS when the SO is loaded.

You need to export the symbols when building the SO, to make them available outside the SO, but you don't need to `import` the symbols as you need to on Windows.

For a more detailed explanation you can refer to this [Visibillity](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) article.

Comment: Any idea why CMake still adds a pointless `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`?